# Assign repeated vector in a dataframe to conditional variables in R

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, rep

With the following dataframe:

```
indiv1 <- c('ID1','ID45','ID85','ID41','ID70','ID32','ID21','ID26')
indiv2 <- c('ID12',0,'ID3',0,'ID10','ID8',0,0)
df <- data.frame(indiv1,indiv2)

> df
  indiv1 indiv2
1    ID1   ID12
2   ID45      0
3   ID85    ID3
4   ID41      0
5   ID70   ID10
6   ID32    ID8
7   ID21      0
8   ID26      0
```

I would like to add a column `V3` to assign a vector `c(1,2,3)` where `indiv2==0` in repetition if the length of `indiv2==0` is bigger than the length of my vector.
I tried with the rep function :

```
df$V3 <- ifelse(df$indiv2==0,rep(1:3,length.out=dim(df[df$indiv2==0,])[1]),0)

> df
  indiv1 indiv2 V3
1    ID1   ID12  0
2   ID45      0  2
3   ID85    ID3  0
4   ID41      0  1
5   ID70   ID10  0
6   ID32    ID8  0
7   ID21      0  3
8   ID26      0  1
```

But it counts the rows where `indiv2!=0` to continue the vector where as I would like :

```
> df
  indiv1 indiv2 V3
1    ID1   ID12  0
2   ID45      0  1
3   ID85    ID3  0
4   ID41      0  2
5   ID70   ID10  0
6   ID32    ID8  0
7   ID21      0  3
8   ID26      0  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table` to do this.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), then specify the logical condition in 'i' (`indiv2 == 0`), we replicate 1:3 with `length.out` as the number of rows (`.N`) and assign (`:=`) it to 'V3', later we replace the NA elements with 0.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[indiv2==0, V3 := rep(1:3, length.out= .N)][is.na(V3), V3 := 0]
df
#   indiv1 indiv2 V3
#1:    ID1   ID12  0
#2:   ID45      0  1
#3:   ID85    ID3  0
#4:   ID41      0  2
#5:   ID70   ID10  0
#6:   ID32    ID8  0
#7:   ID21      0  3
#8:   ID26      0  1
```

---

If we are using `base R`, create a logical vector

```
i1 <- df$indiv2 == 0
```

then create the 'V3' column based on 'i1'

```
df$V3[i1] <- rep(1:3, length.out = sum(i1))
```

and replace the NA to 0

```
df$V3[is.na(df$V3)] <- 0

df$V3
#[1] 0 1 0 2 0 0 3 1
```

---

Using `ifelse` requires length of the 'yes' and 'no' arguments to be the same.  Here, we are doing recycling based on `rep` and it may not work well

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `replace` to do it in one line.

```
df$v3 <- replace(numeric(nrow(df)), df$indiv2 == 0, 1:3)
```

It throws a warning:

> Warning message:
>   In replace(numeric(nrow(df)), df$indiv2 == 0, 1:3) :
>     number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

but produces the desired result.

```
df
  indiv1 indiv2 v3
1    ID1   ID12  0
2   ID45      0  1
3   ID85    ID3  0
4   ID41      0  2
5   ID70   ID10  0
6   ID32    ID8  0
7   ID21      0  3
8   ID26      0  1
```